# Apparent issue with dup and clone in Rails params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm in a Rails controller. I try to take some `params` and change some of the datas to update a model, but I also want to keep the original `params` untouched.

The logical way to go is to use `clone` or `dup` but whatever I try, it fails and changes the original hash.

```
# Original product_params which is set as params.require(:product)
{"name"=>"Product 2",
 "brand"=>"Brand 2",
 "desc"=>"Placeat a sunt eos incidunt temporibus.\r\n\r\nReprehenderit repudiandae amet quibusdam dolorem et. Itaque commodi at.",
 "hs_code"=>"12212121",
 "options_attributes"=>
  {"0"=>{"name"=>"hkjlVariation 4", "suboptions_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"Chkjlhoice 0", "id"=>"582209026b710eded24ecd12"}}, "id"=>"582209026b710eded24ecd13"},
   "1"=>
    {"name"=>"hhVhariation h5kkk",
     "suboptions_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"Choice 0kh", "id"=>"582209026b710eded24ecd14"}, "1"=>{"name"=>"hkjChoice 1", "id"=>"582209026b710eded24ecd16"}, "2"=>{"name"=>"kkk"}},
     "id"=>"582209026b710eded24ecd15"},
   "2"=>{"name"=>"lh", "suboptions_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"klhj"}}}}}

# Method to change the `suboptions_attributes` to `nil`
def product_params_without_suboptions
  copy = product_params.dup
  copy.tap do |product_param|
    product_param[:options_attributes].each do |key, option_attribute|
      unless option_attribute[:suboptions_attributes].nil?
        option_attribute[:suboptions_attributes] = nil
      end
    end
  end
end

# We define product_params
def product_params
  params.require(:product).permit!
end
```

The result of `product_params_without_suboptions` is correct. It set all the `option_attribute` to `nil` but when I try to call `params` or `product_params` it also changed there. **Why isn't dup working here ?**

Comment: Where is your product_params variable coming from? I don't see it defined.

Comment: i added it on my question ;) note : clone doesn't work either

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Working solution

After some investigation, I realized params and its relatives are a `ActionController::Parameters` class and not a simple hash output, which's logical to manipulate it with `require`, `except`, etc. I first thought it would fully act like a hash but it's not the case.

Doing a `clone`, `dup`, `deep_dup` on it will just copy the class and because of the magic of rails, changing anything in this copy will lead to a global change. I don't know the exact reason of this behaviour but I guess there's some **class variables / singleton pattern** going on.

The simplest solution I found was to convert it to a hash via `to_h` so it cut out this problem. You can do `params_hash = params.to_h` and then manipulate the hash and it won't have any consequence on the original `params` object.

Comment: I can still see that original params getting changed

Answer (score 3):

If you have a nested hash and want to duplicate everything, you might be interested by [deep_dup](http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/deep_dup)

Your product_params is an Array of Hashes of Hash, right?
Your example had strings as keys, but your code had symbols. Adapt accordingly.

```
product_params = [{"name"=>"Product 2",
                   "brand"=>"Brand 2",
                   "desc"=>"Placeat a sunt eos incidunt temporibus.\r\n\r\nReprehenderit repudiandae amet quibusdam dolorem et. Itaque commodi at.",
                   "hs_code"=>"12212121",
                   "options_attributes"=>
{"0"=>{"name"=>"hkjlVariation 4", "suboptions_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"Chkjlhoice 0", "id"=>"582209026b710eded24ecd12"}}, "id"=>"582209026b710eded24ecd13"},
 "1"=>
{"name"=>"hhVhariation h5kkk",
 "suboptions_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"Choice 0kh", "id"=>"582209026b710eded24ecd14"}, "1"=>{"name"=>"hkjChoice 1", "id"=>"582209026b710eded24ecd16"}, "2"=>{"name"=>"kkk"}},
 "id"=>"582209026b710eded24ecd15"},
 "2"=>{"name"=>"lh", "suboptions_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"klhj"}}}}}]

require 'pp'

copy = product_params.deep_dup
copy.each do |product_param|
  product_param["options_attributes"].each do |key,option_attribute|
    option_attribute.delete("suboptions_attributes")
  end
end

pp product_params
puts "--------"
pp copy

# [{"name"=>"Product 2",
#   "brand"=>"Brand 2",
#   "desc"=>
#    "Placeat a sunt eos incidunt temporibus.\r\n\r\nReprehenderit repudiandae amet quibusdam dolorem et. Itaque commodi at.",
#   "hs_code"=>"12212121",
#   "options_attributes"=>
#    {"0"=>
#      {"name"=>"hkjlVariation 4",
#       "suboptions_attributes"=>
#        {"0"=>{"name"=>"Chkjlhoice 0", "id"=>"582209026b710eded24ecd12"}},
#       "id"=>"582209026b710eded24ecd13"},
#     "1"=>
#      {"name"=>"hhVhariation h5kkk",
#       "suboptions_attributes"=>
#        {"0"=>{"name"=>"Choice 0kh", "id"=>"582209026b710eded24ecd14"},
#         "1"=>{"name"=>"hkjChoice 1", "id"=>"582209026b710eded24ecd16"},
#         "2"=>{"name"=>"kkk"}},
#       "id"=>"582209026b710eded24ecd15"},
#     "2"=>{"name"=>"lh", "suboptions_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"klhj"}}}}}]
# --------
# [{"name"=>"Product 2",
#   "brand"=>"Brand 2",
#   "desc"=>
#    "Placeat a sunt eos incidunt temporibus.\r\n\r\nReprehenderit repudiandae amet quibusdam dolorem et. Itaque commodi at.",
#   "hs_code"=>"12212121",
#   "options_attributes"=>
#    {"0"=>{"name"=>"hkjlVariation 4", "id"=>"582209026b710eded24ecd13"},
#     "1"=>{"name"=>"hhVhariation h5kkk", "id"=>"582209026b710eded24ecd15"},
#     "2"=>{"name"=>"lh"}}}]
```

Comment: It's an `ActionController::Parameters` and I think that might be the reason i was struggling. The hash / string difference is caused by Rails magic so it works anyway. I changed the clone by a `to_h` to go away from this class and now it seems to works, will write an answer later, but thanks for your input ;)

Comment: ActionController::Parameters has a deep_dup method: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-deep_dup

Answer (score 0):

For me applying only `.to_h` also was causing the original parameters to change.
The solution that worked for me was:

```
params.to_a.to_h.deep_clone
```